# Asus Netbook restarts while loading windows files for installation

Tags: windows-7, boot, installation, netbook, asus-laptop

I recently bought an **Asus X200MA-KX141H X Series Netbook** with DOS pre-installed. I made a bootable USB stick with windows 7 in it and after booting into the windows installation screen, loading windows files fast and displaying the '**Windows is Starting**' message for a few seconds without even the glowing windows logo appearing, the netbook immediately restarts and repeats the whole booting process again. It doesn't proceed into the '**Install Windows**' screen. It shows the **blue screen of death** if XHCI mode is disabled stating that the bios is not compatible with the AHCI. Please help! Thanks in Advance... :)

Answer (score 1):

I also bought an Asus X200MA-KX143D-blue netbook (or notebook or ultrabook, whatever) and had the same problem. I found [this solution topic](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-2131670/installing-windows-x64-asus-x200ma.html) on the net. You need to update your BIOS.

1. So you have to download the latest Bios version from this site: http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/X200MA/HelpDesk_Download
2. Then, upgrade the BIOS. You can follow the instructions found in the [manual](http://www.manualowl.com/m/Asus/X200MA/Manual/402944?page=85).
3. Finally just change to "Windows 7" at the "Advanced/OS Selection" tab of the Bios, as it's written in the solution topic.

Hope this will work ;)

Cheers!

Thank you very much, Radoo!

P.S: ah, and also: I bought a Transcend usb cd/dvd writer (I installed the win with that, I didn't try it with the USB stick solution, but it should work after you updated the BIOS) and it uses usb 2.0, so I had to disable the XHCI mode at the "Advanced/USB Configuration", since that is associated with USB 3.0, I don't know about that thing though =), my uncle helped me with that.